# Browser tools detect CSS twice

Tags: css, browser

When in the Element section, in the right panel, a CSS set of properties is detected twice:

[image: a busy cat]

Same CSS file, same line number, I have only one file named commonCSS. It happens for some elements but not for all. What is going on?

**EDIT:** I tried it with Firefox & Chrome so it's not browser related.

Comment: That looks like chrome or safari, is it doing the same in all browsers? what browsers have you tried? It could be a bug in the browser's inspector.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't including the same style twice?

Comment: Check the source of the page to see if commonCSS is called twice or not

Comment: Omg, it was actually called twice in the source, I wouldn't have guessed, I have no idea why! Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid me: it was called twice in the source... Jeez, this code I'm maintaining is so awfully badly written.